# jQuery - how to treat scroll as single event?

Tags: jquery, scroll

When I bind function to scroll and scroll mousewheel once, the function runs seven or eight times. I want it to run only once when I scroll the mousewheel once, is this possible? I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        alert("Scroll.");          
    }   
    });
});
```

Comment: how much scolling is "once"? Every browser has it's own scrolling resolution. Short scroll may call many scroll events. It's natural.

Comment: By once i mean one uninterrupted scroll no matter how long

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timerId;
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        clearTimeout(timerId)
        timerId = setTimeout(function(){
            alert("Scroll.");          
        }, 200)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CQffC/)

Comment: Wasn't me, I +1'd you. For speed if nothing else ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it is a known problem and solution

Comment: This works perfect for me, but slows bit down i guess..!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use throttle function from [jQuery throttle debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce) plugin.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind('scroll', $.throttle(100, function() {
        console.log('scroll');
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

just a variation of Aruns answer:

Similar approach,just that the event get's fired immediately and is then prevented to be handled again for an interval of time. 
So that you wouldn't have to wait before handling the event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var locked = false
        , timeout;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        //do nothing if still locked
        if(true === locked){
            return false;
        }
        //lock
        locked = true;

        //do something if not locked
        alert('scroll!')

        clearTimeout(timeout)
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            //unlock
            locked = false;         
        }, 1000)
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution is working. I fail to see how it's not rated higher.

Comment: This should be accepted answer and highest rated for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If by "once" you mean, once-per-page-load, 
you could unbind the event in the listener with the `off()` method.
http://api.jquery.com/off/

There's also the possibility of namespacing events like:

`scroll.namespace`
is still the same event, but you can unbind it specifically.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll.myEvent', function() {
        $(window).off('scroll.myEvent');
        alert("Scroll.");          
    }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect scrolling only once, use this:

```
$(function () {
    var done = false;
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       if (!done){
           alert("Scroll.");
           done = true;
       }
   });
});
```

but if you want to detect every scroll event, try something like the answer 4