# Prevent jQuery .scroll function to run while doing what's inside the .scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to prevent jQuery `.scroll` function to run while doing what's inside the `.scroll` function.
The reason is because it may run twice and cause problems for me.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
       

// do stuff

}
```

I tried:

```
var carRun = true;   
     if (canRun==true){
            $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
            canRun=false;
    
            // do stuff
    
            canRun=true;
    } 
}
```

and It didn't fix the problem.

Edit:

These are tests of things I tried and aren't working for me:
No.1:

```
     var canRun = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (canRun == true){
   if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50 ) {
            canRun = false; 

            // Are there more posts to load?
            if (pageNum <= max) {
                console.log(max);
                // Show that we're working.
                $('#loadmoreLink').text('Loading posts...');

                $('.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .post',
                    function() {
                        // Update page number and nextLink.
                        console.log("The number of the next page to load: " + pageNum);
                        pageNum++;
                        console.log("The number of the next page to load after increment: " + pageNum);
                        nextLink = 'http://www.example.com.br/page/' + pageNum + '/';
                        console.log("The link of the next page: " + nextLink);

                        // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts')
                            .before('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>');
                        console.log("--------END AJAX-------------");
                        // Update the button message.
                        if(pageNum <= max) {
                            $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('Load More Posts');
                        } else {
                            $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('No more posts to load.');
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        canRun = true;
        }
    }
    });
```

No.2:

```
     var canRun = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50 ) && (canRun == true ) ) {
            canRun = false; 

            // Are there more posts to load?
            if (pageNum <= max) {
                console.log(max);
                // Show that we're working.
                $('#loadmoreLink').text('Loading posts...');

                $('.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .post',
                    function() {
                        // Update page number and nextLink.
                        console.log("The number of the next page to load: " + pageNum);
                        pageNum++;
                        console.log("The number of the next page to load after increment: " + pageNum);
                        nextLink = 'http://www.example.com.br/page/' + pageNum + '/';
                        console.log("The link of the next page: " + nextLink);

                        // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts')
                            .before('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>');
                        console.log("--------END AJAX-------------");
                        // Update the button message.
                        if(pageNum <= max) {
                            $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('Load More Posts');
                        } else {
                            $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('No more posts to load.');
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        canRun = true;
        }
    });
```

This one worked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // The number of the next page to load (/page/x/).
    var pageNum = parseInt(pbd_alp.startPage);
    // The maximum number of pages the current query can return.
    var max = parseInt(pbd_alp.maxPages);   
    // The link of the next page of posts.
    var nextLink = pbd_alp.nextLink;
    //what page am I on? 
    var whatPage = pbd_alp.theTitle;
    //console.log(whatPage);
    
    /**
     * Replace the traditional navigation with our own,
     * but only if there is at least one page of new posts to load.
     */
    if(pageNum <= max) {
        // Insert the "More Posts" link.
        $('#content').append('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"  ></div>')
        .append('<p id="pbd-alp-load-posts"><a href="javaScript:void(0);" id="loadmoreLink" onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Click\', \'LoadMore\', \''+ whatPage +'\']);">Load More Posts</a></p>');
            
        // Remove the traditional navigation.
        $('.navigation').remove();
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Load new posts when the link is clicked.
     */

    var timerId = false;
    var canRun = true;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

        if(canRun == true){
           if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50 ) {
                    canRun = false; 
        
                    // Are there more posts to load?
                    if (pageNum <= max) {
                        console.log(max);
                        // Show that we're working.
                        $('#loadmoreLink').text('Loading posts...');

                        console.log("start loading things from ");
                        $('.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .post', function() {
                                console.log("Im in da callback, loading has finished");
                                // Update page number and nextLink.

                            //the target of load is '.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum
                            //pageNum must'nt be changed before loading.
                                console.log("The number of the next page to load: " + pageNum);
                                pageNum++;
                                console.log("The number of the next page to load after increment: " + pageNum);
                                nextLink = 'http://www.example.com.br/page/' + pageNum + '/';
                                console.log("The link of the next page: " + nextLink);

        
                                // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                                $('#pbd-alp-load-posts').before('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>');
                                
                                // Update the button message.
                                if(pageNum <= max) {
                                    $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('Load More Posts');
                                } else {
                                    $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('No more posts to load.');
                                }
                                
                                //and now that I have finished, we can load more stuff
                                canRun = true;
                        });
                    }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your if statement to check if `canRun` is true will kind of need to be inside the `scroll` handler function...

Comment: tried somwthing else: 

`var canRun = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50 ) && (canRun==true) ) {
   canRun = false;

                      //do stuff 

                       canRun = true;
             }
});
`

Am I doing sonthing wrong because it's still not working.

Comment: Comments aren't exactly great for more than small (single line) sections of code, I'd suggest editing your question with any additional pieces of code you've tried, and explaining exactly what problem you're seeing. You may also need to expand `// do stuff` to include the actual code - if that's calling asynchronous functions then `canRun = true` may be running before your code has actually finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If statement goes inside the function. Also, you need to define the variable as `canRun` not `carRun`. Otherwise, you won't be setting a variable with global scope.

```
var canRun = true;   

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (canRun==true){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
            canRun=false;

            // do stuff

            canRun=true;
        } 
     }
}
```

Also, consider the top answer here as an alternative: [jQuery - how to treat scroll as single event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144159/jquery-how-to-treat-scroll-as-single-event) It will only allow one function call every 200ms.

Comment: I'll try it in a minuet. 
I just want to test this before: 

`var canRun = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50 ) && (canRun==true) ) {
   canRun = false;

                      //do stuff 

                       canRun = true;
             }
});
`

Am I doing sonthing wrong because it's still not working.

Comment: I'll update my answer. The other problem here is that you're defining the variable as `carRun` with an R, then using it as `canRun` with an N.

Comment: I figured this part out already, sorry my fault. with the fixed code it's still not working. 

I'll edit my main post and add the full code.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Does the stuff inside the function take a really long time to accomplish? Is it possible that the function fires once, finishes really fast, and then fires again on the next scroll event?

Comment: I have a wordpress blog. This is a loadmore function that loads posts when scrolled to the bottom of the page. 
when I grab the scroller with the mouse and move it up and down fast - the console.log inside the scroll function shows up multiple times.

Comment: You're not actually doing the AJAX call in this code though. Executing a few writes to the console and such is going to take your browser virtually no time at all. What's happening here is that the code is working, but your function is executing really, really fast, and canRun is getting set back to true in time for the next scroll event. You're going to have to take a different approach if you want to process multiple scroll events as one...

Comment: hmm.. Maybe I can give it 5 seconds to set 'canRun' back itself  to true. Do you think that something like this will work?

Comment: Yes... I just added a link for some code that will do something very similar.

Comment: I edited the main post with the one that worked for me at the end. 
Thank you very very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set an window property like window.scroll_working which will be set to true in your if loop and before if functionality. Logic:

```
$(window).scroll(callback)

function callback() {
    if(window.working) return;

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {

    window.working = true;
    // do your stuff
    } 
    window.working = false
}
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SgPL9/4/)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/CQffC/2/

It only allows one run of the scrolling code every 5 seconds, but it executes immediately when it's allowed. You could, of course, modify this to your liking.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timerId = false;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if (timerId==false) {
            console.log('here');

            /* Do Stuff Here */

            timerId = setTimeout(function(){
                    timerId = false;
            }, 5000)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I speculated in the comments, the issue (aside from the `if` statement initially being in the wrong location) is that you're beginning an asynchronous process (in this case an AJAX request using jQuery's `.load()` function) inside your `scroll` event handler. That means that your current execution order is essentially this:

1. Set `canRun` to false
2. Start the AJAX request
3. Set `canRun` to true
4. Receive a response to the AJAX request and do something with it

You obviously want your execution order to be:

1. Set `canRun` to false
2. Start the AJAX request
3. Receive a response to the AJAX request and do something with it
4. Set `canRun` to true

How do you do that?

Set `canRun` to true in your current callback for the AJAX request (the function passed as the second argument to `.load()`) rather than immediately after the call to `.load()`.